# How do you decompress bytes compressed with Lempel-Ziv Haruyasu algorithm in .NET?

Tags: .net

How do you decompress one of those LZH formats in .NET (hint: I would prefer to use functionality already implemented, instead of implementing if possible).

The situation I am in is that a server sends me an XML document; that document has some compressed data in Base64 encoding.

After getting the bytes from the XML, I've blindly tried `DeflateStream`, hoping it would work. It didn't work; it returned the "InvalidDataException - Unknown block type. Stream might be corrupted" error, and I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

There is a utility that you may be able to call from your application (not free but not expensive) at:

[Link1](http://www.bitzipper.com/lzh-file.html)

There is a CodeProject article about a component you could use at:

[Link2](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/cs_interface_7zip.aspx)

Comment: Aren't those for unzipping real lzh files, with headers and whatnot ? I have a byte array that just the algorithm has been applied to. Sorry if i'm unclear - lack of knowledge on my part.