# Extract file from LZH archive

Tags: c#, .net, archive

I have **LZH** archive (.lzh, .lha extensions of archive), and need to extract file from it in .NET Framework 4? Does .NET Framework 4 have some built in toolset for this?

Comment: [It appears](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LHA_(file_format)) that you need to install the Japanese Windows locale to get native support for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you decompress bytes compressed with Lempel-Ziv Haruyasu algorithm in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7721223/1838048)

Answer (score 2):

I ported an LHA Java decompression library to .NET called [LHA Decompressor](https://github.com/headkaze/LHADecompressor).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much to the author above. I have posted a simple implementation of it for reference.

```
            //Extracts all files in the .lzh archive
            LhaFile lhaFile = null;
            byte[] dest = new byte[8];
            List<string> extractedFileList = new List<string>();

            lhaFile = new LhaFile(filePath, Encoding.UTF7);
            IEnumerator<LhaEntry> enumerator = lhaFile.GetEnumerator();

            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                string fileName = enumerator.Current.GetPath();
                LhaEntry lhaEntry = lhaFile.GetEntry(fileName);
                dest = lhaFile.GetEntryBytes(lhaEntry);

                File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(extractionPath, fileName), dest);

                string fullPath = Path.Combine(extractionPath, fileName);
                extractedFileList.Add(fullPath);

            }

            lhaFile.Close();
```